# Python 2.7.6, some strings won't print

Tags: python, string, printing

" I'm writing a script in Python 2.7.6 that calculates the roots of a quadratic equation and prints them along with some strings of text. For some reason, the strings won't print in this script, I keep getting an error message that I'm using the improper syntax. I'm pretty sure that I'm using the correct syntax for strings, because I can get them to print under other circumstances, but not at the end of this particular script. I'm trying to get it to print out

"Roots to this equation are
"(first root, whatever it is)
"as well as
"(second root, whatever it is)

"So far, I haven't figured out why the strings at the end of this script won't print, I am totally open to any suggestions. I have tried a number of different strings and string methods, unfortunately so far none have worked. I'm very new to this, so please don't be afraid of over-explaining :)

```
# First, enter the variables a, b, and c
a=2
b=4
c=-2
# Define the variables that would appear under the radical in the written equation
b_squared=b**2
four_a_c=4 * a * c
under_the_radical=b_squared-four_a_c
radicalize=under_the_radical**.5 # Take the square root of the values under the radical
# Define the remaining variables in the equation
neg_b=-1*b
two_a=2*a
x_subone=neg_b + radicalize 
x_subtwo=neg_b - radicalize
x_one=x_subone/two_a
x_two=x_subtwo/two_a
print ‘Roots to this equation are’
print x_one
print ‘as well as’
print x_two
```

Comment: what is printing, and what isn't? Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you're getting.

Comment: You may have typed normal vertical quotes `'` that got converted into `‘` and `’` by your text editor's "smart-quotes" feature. So you need to disable that feature when editing code.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the lines `Roots to this equation are` and `as well as` are not printing. The reason is because you are not enclosing the strings in the correct quotation marks. Use standard ASCII quotes, either single or double, not backticks, curly quotes, or other stylized markings. The following will work:

```
print 'Roots to this equation are'
print x_one
print 'as well as'
print x_two
```

Note in the syntax highlighting how they are different colors than the "strings" in your code above.